# Why chromium browser sometimes asks user to confirm refreshing a POST URL and sometimes not

Tags: post, form-submit, chromium

I've a dummy HTML form.

```
<form action="/to/my/url" method="POST">
  <input type="submit" value="My submit button">
</form>
```

When the user click submit, the browser make a new HTTP call on /to/my/url with the verb POST.

Using Firefox, if a click refresh or hit Ctrl+R, the browser asks me to confirm the action and **that's perfectly fine**. That's the expected behavior to prevent double-submissions. I know about the POST-redirect-get pattern and I use it, that's not the issue here.

Using Chromium, I sometimes have this behavior but most of the time, I've not and I don't understand why. I've tried many things like using

```
<button type=submit>
```

or adding a *hidden* field, setting ids and names, etc but i don't understand why i can still hit Ctrl+R and Chromium keeps sending POST without telling me that's a double-submission. I had the message once, but i'm not able to reproduce.

How Chromium decide if the user must be prompted for double-submission or not? How my form must be designed to make Chromium works properly, like Firefox do?